# /dev/sde install disk is seen as /dev/sda at boot time

Tags: linux-kernel, udev, initramfs, block-device, initrd

I'm SystemImager image deployment software developper.
I'm trying to support external disk drivers, but I'm stuck with a silly problem.

When I run preinstall scripts (udev has already settled) I fetch via network the driver (example, a specific megaraid_sas.ko that support old hardware on RHEL 8)

When the driver loads, it recognize the disk as /dev/sde
Install works fine (EFI System), initramfs are rebuilt to include the driver.
grub2-mkconfig generates a config file with root=(hd4,gpt2)
efibootmgr creates the correct entry (it uses UUID)

Unfortunately, when rebooting grub fails to find the kernel (hd4 while BIOS sees hd0) => 1st problem.
When I fix that, => 2nd problem: kernel loads the megaraid_sas.ko (as it is in intrants file) and this megaraid disk is seen as /dev/sda !
If I try to continue from emergency mode, mounting by hand /sysroot, lvm fails trying to find /dev/sde....

Is there a way to:
-> At install time tell UDEV to not use /dev/sda until I say it's ok? (best solution as it would also solve the grub and lvm issues)
or
at boot time, is there a way to tell kernel that megaraid_sas should use /dev/sde?

I tried to look at the anaconda dracut module, but was unable to understand how the OEMDRV is handled after reboot. (they download the driver from network far after disk devices have been detected by dev).

Any idea?

Comment: Drive names are largely determined by initialisation order, so you can't rely on it being the same each time. Use UUIDs, labels, or disk IDs.

Comment: I know that, but grub2-mkconfig uses that order. for example, when I install, I insmod the megaraid_sas after all disks are initialized and the raid drive appears as /dev/sde thus grub2-mkconfig uses (hd4,gpt2) for root, but when I create the initrd that includes the driver, the raid device is recognized and the raid drive is seen as /dev/sda. when booting the bios sees the raid drive as 1st disk, and thus grub should use (hd0,gpt2) as root device instead of (hd4,gpt2). and unfortunately, no UUID can help here.

Comment: grub is capable of using UUIDs or Labels to specify drives and partitions in its config files.  In fact, it is recommended to do so.

Comment: How do I tell grub to do so? By default, if I run grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/almalinux/grub.cfg, the resulting file has a set root=(hd4,gpt2) which is wrong at boot time as the disk is seen as 1st disk and is (hd0,gpt2).